# pass data by user to another class

Tags: java, arrays, class, netbeans

I try pass student names from main class to students class but I get error through runtime.

Main class is

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
              Students students =new Students ();
              Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
              String [] name = new String [5];
              for (int i =0; i <=4; i++){
              System.out.print("Enter student name " + (i+1) + " : ");
                       name [i]= in.next();  
              }
              students.SetData(name);
              students.GetData();

     }// Main
```

Students class is

```
public class Students {
    private String Names [] = new String [5]; 
    
    public void SetData (String [] Names){
              for (int i=0 ; i <= Names.length; i++){
                       this.Names [i] = Names[i] ; //HERE is my error
              } //for 
    } //SetData method
    
    public void  GetData (){
              for (int i=0 ; i <= Names.length; i++){
                       System.out.println("Name of student " + (i+1) + " is " +Names[i]);
              } //for
    } //GetData mehtod 
} //Students Class
```

Also how can I make my program check if user entered STRING or not ?

THANKS ALL

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by "_check if user entered **STRING**..._"?   Ultimately, **all input is strings**.

Comment: use `if (name.matches("^[a-zA-Z]*$")) `. Alter regular expression as per your need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write
`i < Names.length`
in your loops, so they terminate one step earlier.

`Names.length == 5`, *i.e.* one greater than the last valid index.

**Nitpicks:**
You shouldn't start variables with capital letters, they're reserved for class names. Using space before the `[]` array operator also looks weird.

Answer (score 1):

> Also how can I make my program check if user entered STRING or not ?

Use regular expressions to validate user inputs:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    isValidName("John  Doe");
    isValidName("John1 Doe");
}   

public static boolean isValidName(String name){
    boolean isValid = name.matches("[a-zA-Z]*\s*[a-zA-Z]*$");
    if(isValid) {
        System.out.println(name + " is a valid name");
    } else {
        System.out.println(name + " is not a valid name");
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Output:

```
John  Doe is a valid name
John1 Doe is not a valid name
```

Change the pattern `[a-zA-Z]*\s*[a-zA-Z]*$` as *per* your needs.
For more information refer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: If you don't like the edit feel free to rollback

Answer (score 1):

To accept **dynamic no of name** entry use **ArrayList** in stead of **array of string** and *to validate name as string use the pattern matching feature with regular expression.*

```
class  TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Students students =new Students ();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        String input = new String();
        do{
            System.out.print("Enter student name or 'e' to exit : ");
            input = scanner.next();
            if(isValidName(input) && (!input.equals("e"))){
                names.add(input);
            }
        }while(!input.equals("e"));

        students.SetData(names);
        students.GetData();
        
    }

    public static boolean isValidName(String name){
        String regExp = "[a-zA-Z]*\\s*[a-zA-Z]*$";
        boolean isValid = name.matches(regExp);
        System.out.println("isValid :" + isValid);
        return isValid;
    }

}

class Students {

    private String names [];
    
    public void SetData (List<String> names){
         this.names = names.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
    
    public void  GetData (){
        for (int i=0 ; i < names.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Name of student " + (i+1) + " is " +names[i]);
        }
    }
}
```